# simple_form_for error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2), in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, simple-form

I am getting wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) error for simple_form_for tag in rails 3 (with haml). 
Interestingly it was working fine some moment back.

```
= simple_form_for(:user,@user, :url => user_path, :remote => true, :html => { :id => "locate", :class=>"locateform" }) do |f
```

any pointers/help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This part looks suspicious.

```
:user,@user,
```

Did you acciddentally delete the `:as =>` ? I think it should be

```
:user, :as => @user
```